# CSS Firefox Vs Chrome Inconsistent height and position output

Tags: html, css

I am stucked with a problem of css inconsistency between my browsers (Chrome and Firefox) in `http://204.197.252.143/~themainr` .

The height of the search button is not identical when compared.

Plus the searchbox is not well aligned in firefox as shown in the images below:

This is the view in google chrome (this is the desired output in all browsers):

[image]

This one is in the firefox:

[image]

I tried adjust the float to right of the search section but its just messes up the look of the it.

Is there any a good technique to display this correctly?

Comment: without the CSS code in question its going to be hard to help. just the css for the problematic sections should be fine. You could be missing a -moz- identifier/s. Also the html elements in question would be very useful

Comment: @Nomad101 He provides the live URL...

Comment: I was just saying the exact css and html in question would help people respond is all. I for one am not apt to visit ip address's.

Comment: I edited my question title already. 

Actually this scenario is new to me. And i think I'm missing with some basics in positioning. But this scenario is specific, i really don't know if what element is causing the incorrect display. 

Im using wordpress with this one.

Maybe a css pro here can point out what is my error. Just hopeful to solve this one in this site because lots of pros here :)

Comment: oh I see what you are saying. Yea it is going to take a lot of playing with values. it is just how it is done for the finer tweaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the height of the `input` search box, you can do this by setting its `font-size` property or by setting its `height` property, this ensures it is being rendered the same height in both browsers.

To get rid of the extra space on the right and align the search box with the menu below it,  set `float: right` on `.menu-main-menu-container`:

```
li.search input[type="text"] {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EBEBEB;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    font-family: 'waukegan';
    font-size: 25px;        
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    width: 205px;
    height: 32px; /* Add this line */   
}

.menu-main-menu-container {
    float: right; /* Change this line */
    max-width: 94%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solution answered my question completely and correctly. Its easier for me to edit the responsive part of the site with your solution :)

Answer (score 8):

lol, all the tools in the world doesn't replace just playing with it sometimes.

I was able to get the desired results by changing the font-size of the search text box from 25px to 24px.  In both firefox and chrome it seemed to look good to me.

I was able to do this by using firebug for firefox and the built in developer tools for chrome.

Learn to use them because they are very important for tweaks like this.

Good luck

EDIT more detailed example of what I changed

```
li.search input[type="text"] {
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #ebebeb;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    width: 205px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'waukegan';
    font-size: 24px; /*originally font-size: 25px;*/
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I agree. Actually I used only the css I know. 
Thanks for the suggestion. Still modifying my code

Comment: @Kenneth:
Wow. It worked. Thank very much for the idea. But i still need to make the search textbox align with the sidebar below.

Comment: google is your friend... As is firebug and chrome developer tools. :)

Comment: @Jed, check my answer, it fixes your alignment issue.

Answer (score 2):

just add this one command to your current css (style.css file on line 203)

```
li.search input[type="text"] {
 height: 32px;
}
```

enjoy

Comment: thanks but i tried that one already. And it didn't work. The solution I tried was from Kenneth and it worked. But thank you very much by the way. :)